podman 5.1 - dependency on yocto/linux versiosn
does podman 5.1 have any specific minimum version of Yocto build or linux kernel versions to be avaliale for its working?
i am trying to upgrade my podman version on my existing setup . Hence need to know if it would need any  kernel level or compilation environment changes
